# I can't get my Access tables to fit on their pages

Tags: ms-access

I've been trying for a while but it seems I can't get my table to fit on the page.

Picture of the table I'm trying to print:

[image: Picture of the table im trying to print]

Is there a way to make it smaller?

Comment: You can't automatically have it fit it on a page. You can reduce the margins and remove the headings in Page Setup but you can't change the actual size/scale of the text because you are directly printing the table. You could find other ways including a report, or exporting to Excel for a scaled print.

Comment: I hope these are mock records!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using reports.

Tables in Access are just for storing data, nothing more, nothing less. Reports in Access can store layout, print settings, and much more.

To create a report off a table, just go to that table, and click "Create Report" in the "Create" tab.

To have a datasheet on a report, go to the "Create" tab, click on "Create blank report", and drag your table unto the blank report. The look is nearly the same, but now you can determine the size the table can take on the report. Note that column width is still bound to your table. You also have more control over layout, page numbering, margins, headings, etc.